# UnitStep producing unclean boundary

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to do the SliceDensityPlot3D which uses UnitStep function

```
a = 1; d = 0.001; b = a/2;
 Show[SliceDensityPlot3D[
 kx^2 ky + kz, {UnitStep[ UnitStep[ky - kx] - UnitStep[kz]] (kx + ky) == a, kx - ky == a, UnitStep[-ky] (kx + kz) == a, kx - kz == a, 
   ky + kz == a, ky - kz == a, kx + ky == -a, kx - ky == -a, 
   kx + kz == -a, kx - kz == -a, ky + kz == -a, ky - kz == -a, 
   kx == 0, ky == 0, kz == 0, kx == ky}, {kx, -1, 1}, {ky, -1, 
   1}, {kz, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{kx, ky, kz}, 
    Abs[kx + ky] < a + d && Abs[kx - ky] < a + d && 
     Abs[kx + kz] < a + d && Abs[kx - kz] < a + d && 
     Abs[ky + kz] < a + d && Abs[ky - kz] < a + d], 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Axes -> False], 
 Graphics3D[{Thickness -> 0.001, Black, Arrowheads[0.04],
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.35, 0, 0}}]],
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.35, 0}}]],
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.35}}]],
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(x\)]\)", Black, 
     FontSize -> 25, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], {1.25, 0.0, 0.16}],
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(y\)]\)", Black, 
     FontSize -> 25, FormatType -> "Helvetica"], {-0.04, 1.25, 
     0.08}],
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(z\)]\)", Black, 
     FontSize -> 25, FormatType -> "Helvetica"], {0.15, 0, 1.24}]}], 
 Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2.5, 2}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

Everything is as expected, except the boundaries of the UnitStep functions I have used.

[image]

See the unclean boundaries around $kx+ky=a$ and $kx+kz=a$. Any idea how to clean this or any other work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried cranking up `PlotPoints`? Or reformulating in terms of `Piecewise[]`?

Comment: `PlotPoints` was my first guess and it did not help. I check with `Piecewise[{{1, ky <= 0}, {0, ky > 0}}] (kx + kz) == a`, but it messed up the whole plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have got what I wanted. The trick was to use the `UnitStep` in the `RegionFunction` and not in the definition of the planes. The code goes

```
a= 1; d = 0.0001; b = a/2;
Show[SliceDensityPlot3D[(\[Pi] kx)^2 \[Pi] ky \[Pi] kz, {(kx + ky) == 
    a, kx - ky == a, (kx + kz) == a, kx - kz == a, ky + kz == a, 
   kz - ky == a, kx == 0, ky == 0, kz == 0, kx == ky}, {kx, -1, 
   1}, {ky, -1, 1}, {kz, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{kx, ky, kz}, 
    Abs[kx + ky] < a + d && Abs[kx - ky] < a + d && 
     Abs[kx + kz] < a + d && Abs[kx - kz] < a + d && 
     Abs[ky + kz] < a + d && Abs[ky - kz] < a + d && 
     UnitStep[ky]*UnitStep[kx - ky]*UnitStep[kz - 10 d] < 1], 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Axes -> False], 
 Graphics3D[{Thickness -> 0.002, 
   Line[{{0, 0, 1}, {b, b, b}, {0, 1, 0}, {-b, b, b}, {0, 0, 1}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {-b, -b, -b}, {0, -1, 0}, {b, -b, -b}, {0, 
      0, -1}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 1}, {-b, -b, b}, {0, -1, 0}, {b, -b, b}, {0, 0, 1}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {-b, b, -b}, {0, 1, 0}, {b, b, -b}, {0, 0, -1}}],
    Line[{{-b, -b, -b}, {0, 0, -1}, {-b, b, -b}, {-1, 0, 
      0}, {-b, -b, -b}}], 
   Line[{{-1, 0, 0}, {-b, b, b}, {0, 0, 1}, {-b, -b, b}, {-1, 0, 0}}],
    Line[{{b, -b, -b}, {0, 0, -1}, {b, b, -b}, {1, 0, 
      0}, {b, -b, -b}}], 
   Line[{{1, 0, 0}, {b, b, 0}, {b, b, b}, {0, 0, 1}, {b, -b, b}, {1, 
      0, 0}}], Line[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {b, b, 0}}], Black, Arrowheads[0.04],
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.35, 0, 0}}]],
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.35, 0}}]],
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.35}}]],
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(x\)]\)", Black, 
     FontSize -> 25, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], {1.25, 0.0, -0.14}],
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(y\)]\)", Black, 
     FontSize -> 25, FormatType -> "Helvetica"], {-0.04, 1.5, 0.08}],
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(z\)]\)", Black, 
     FontSize -> 25, FormatType -> "Helvetica"], {0.15, 0, 1.24}]}],
 Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi/2.5, 2}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

And the result,

[image]

Please comment.